# How to change audio port when the sound is from the webview for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

can someone please help me out in figuring out how to play around with the audio output when the sound is coming from webview?

I've learnt this audioSession and figured on how to change the port from speaker to earpiece (bottom speaker to top speaker) in iOS when the audio is playing from our app, however, my requirement is to change the port when the audio is from webView.

I tried playing the YouTube in the webview, unfortunately, audiosession doesn't seem to work with webView.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems like controlling audio from Webview seems impossible. If you want to play Youtube videos try [YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper).

Comment: Hi @Sreekuttan thanks for the help. Unfortunately, our requriement is to control it through webview. Youtube is just the sample app that I was trying.